# Android Bottom navigation Localization

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, android-drawable, bottomnavigationview

I'm successfully localizing my android Application but issue is that, i'm struggling to change localize language of option menus , and bottom navigation tabs. unable to solve that issue. please help me.
Thanks in (Advance).

Comment: Can you show us your menu .xml?

Comment: Have u tried adding strings to the menus?

Answer (score 6):

Clear & reinflate them like

```
navView.getMenu().clear();
navView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menus_options);
```

Or do below before setContentView() in activity

```
Locale locale;
locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
activity.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
        activity.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: I'm working on nav graph with bottom navigation can you plz explain it ,how can i use above code that u shared

Answer (score 0):

After **navView.getMenu().clear()** the locale is reset, so you need to do the following to get your language fixed

```
Locale locale;
locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
activity.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
        activity.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```